# How to customize or localize the error texts in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a new user form. I am using `Validator` from "`react-admin-base-adminkit`". I want to customize error messages or translate them to another language. For example, there is an error for e-mail:

"*An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "IX_Users_email"*"

I want to change it like:

"*Please, enter a different e-mail*"

How can I do that?

```
import { Validator } from "react-admin-base-adminkit";
...
 <Validator name="email" type="required">
     <Input
         type="email"
         value={data.email}
         onChange={(a) => setData({ email: a.currentTarget.value })}
     />
</Validator>
```